# Rails simple_form association help with option tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

In my form I have:

```
<%= f.association :virksomhed, :collection => Virksomhed.all(:order => 'navn'), :prompt => "Vælg virksomhed" %>
```

In view I have this:

[image]

I instead of the object I want to display the name (navn on danish) of the companyies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the :label_method option:

```
<%= f.association :virksomhed, :collection => Virksomhed.all(:order => 'navn'), :prompt => "Vælg virksomhed", :label_method=>:navn %>
```